# Can I use Lua-based tools to create games for Apple Store?

Tags: lua, mac-app-store

Would making a game in Lua via a framework like [Love](https://love2d.org/) ( where everything is nicely packaged) infringe mac app store rules?

Comment: Yes, I think it would. The app store now requires that all apps be sandboxed. [See here](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/11/02/apple-to-require-sandboxing-in-mac-app-store-apps-as-of-march-20/).

Comment: @Hassan: What does sandboxing have to do with Lua?

Comment: I rather doubt there will be any issue. However, I am not particularly familiar with the Mac App Store rules so I can't say that definitively. But the only issue with the iOS app store that Lua had was the ban on interpreted code (not using Apple's JavaScriptCore), and even that was relaxed to only apply to downloaded code.

Comment: my biggest worries are " Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected" and "Apps must be packaged and submitted using Apple's packaging technologies included in Xcode "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Lua-based tools to create games. Löve doesn't work on IOS, but there are others that do. The most popular ones are [Corona SDK](http://www.coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/) and [Moai SDK](http://getmoai.com/).

Comment: The tools I've mentioned have been used to make games for the Mac App store.